# How to create an async web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous

Does anyone have informations or a link to a working tutorial to create an async webservice in java? It needs to be called by a windows phone application.

Two friends and myself are working on a project. The last week we decided to change the OS for the client side to Windows phone.

The old web service was sync :

```
    package de.morpheus.chatbot.service;

import javax.jws.*;

import de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB;
import de.morpheus.chatbot.model.BotInit;
@WebService
public class ChatbotService {

    private BotInit chatbot = new BotInit(new DataSourceDB(),BotInit.DEFAULT_AIML_EXTENSIONS);

    @WebMethod
    public String communicate(String input) {
        return this.chatbot.processInput(input);
    }
  }
```

But we did not manage to call that webservice via the Windows phone application, because it only accepts async web services.

On the client side we used this tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937(v=vs.95).aspx
to connect to the web service.

What do we need to change in the web service? I guess we need to rewrite the hole web service, but I have no clue, how to make it async.

Any help would be appreciated.
Greetings 
SteveM

Edit: 
When I try to run the app on my Windows phone, I get an exception in Visual Studio (even before the auto-generated Service Class calls the Java Service), saying: 
"The contract 'ChatbotService' contains synchronous operations, which are not supported in Silverlight. 
Split the operations into "Begin" and "End" parts and set the AsyncPattern property on the OperationContractAttribute to 'true'. Note that you do not have to make the same change on the server."

The last sentence is the most confusing to me. It looks like I need to make changes on the client side, but my actual belief is that I need to change the ws on the serverside.

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you get? The link you provided only says that the _call to the web service_  is asynchronous, which the server part needs to care absolutely not a whit about.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement a chat service via web-services? Just a word of advise you are opening yourself for a world of pain here. Go look at eJabberD and other open source chat servers and clients before going down this route.